# Кнопки съезжают при открытии клавиатуры

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-button

**Методом тыка понял что проблема уходит как только удаляю RecyclerView с картами ID**

Состояние до открытия клавиатуры
[image: до открытия клавиатуры]
После (внимание на четыре правые кнопки)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопки прикреплены к нижней части.

Что только не пробовал, засовывал `RecyclerView` в разные `Layout`, мне кажется я всё перепробовал... Повторюсь, всё приходит в норму как только удаляю `RecyclerView`. Как можно решить проблему сжатия?

Оставлю только основной код, если понадобится код кнопок, пишите.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/Main_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include2">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:splitMotionEvents="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/patronymic_edit_text">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

И код класса

```
class EditUserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recycleView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_user)
        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.empty_toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        recycleView = findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view)
        recycleView.let {
            it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            it.adapter = CardAdapter(CardFactory.createList(10))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте прописать в `AndroidManifest.xml` у Activity

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

В этом случае контент будет находиться выше клавиатуры.

Или

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"> 
</activity>
```

В этом случае клавиатура будет находиться поверх контента.

В любом случае, Вам нужно смотреть в сторону `windowSoftInputMode`. Другие параметры можно найти [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Comment: +1 `adjustNothing` исправит ситуацию